# python similar filter related code, different output

Tags: python

a.py:

```
def all():
    n = 2
    while True:
        yield n
        n = n + 1

y = all()
number = next(y)
print(number)
y = filter(lambda x: x % number != 0, y)
number = next(y)
print(number)
y = filter(lambda x: x%3 != 0, y)
print(next(y))
y = filter(lambda x: x%5 != 0, y)
print(next(y))
y = filter(lambda x: x%7 != 0, y)
```

b.py:

```
def all():
    n = 2
    while True:
        yield n
        n = n + 1

y = all()
number = next(y)
print(number)
y = filter(lambda x: x % number != 0, y)
num = next(y)
print(num)
y = filter(lambda x: x%3 != 0, y)
print(next(y))
y = filter(lambda x: x%5 != 0, y)
print(next(y))
y = filter(lambda x: x%7 != 0, y)
```

I am trying write a script that print primes.

the output of a.py are: 2 3 4 7.
the output of b.py are: 2 3 5 7.
The variables, num and number, are never used after `y = filter(lambda x: x%3 != 0, y)`
why the output are different after `y = filter(lambda x: x%3 != 0, y)`?

Comment: @pingu I thought the same thing when I first looked but the line `number = next(y)` and `num = next(y)` are the difference in these, and because `number` is used in the lambda, when its changed in `a.py` it affects what the lambda produces

Comment: I think you have accidentally pasted the outputs the wrong way around. `a.py` outputs `2 3 4 7` whereas `b.py` outputs `2 3 5 7`.

Comment: @Lecdi thanks for your reminding~ I just fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using different variables in `a` and `b`. The different is because you set a `lambda` that will use the value of the variable `number` as part of the calculation.

In `a.py` you set the `number` before the filter, then you change the value of `number` after you create the filter, this changes the value inside the filter.

In `b.py` you set the `number` before the filter then you create a new var called `num` after the filter, since this is a different var it doesn't alter the outcome of the filter.

We can illustrate this with a simple example.

```py
print("example A")
number = 2
my_lambda = lambda x: x + number
print(my_lambda(2))
number = 5
print(my_lambda(20))
print(my_lambda(200))

print("example B")
number = 2
my_lambda = lambda x: x + number
print(my_lambda(2))
num = 5
print(my_lambda(20))
print(my_lambda(200))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
example A
4
25
205
example B
4
22
202
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def all():
    n = 2
    while True:
        yield n
        n = n + 1

y = all()
number = next(y)

y = filter(lambda x: x % number != 0, y)

# After the filter now y is similar to

def fun():
    for x in all():
        if x % number != 0:
            yield x

y = filter(lambda x: x%3 != 0, y)

# After the filter now y is similar to

def fun():
    for x in all():
        if x % number != 0 and x % 3 != 0:
            yield x

y = filter(lambda x: x%5 != 0, y)

# After the filter now y is similar to

def fun():
    for x in all():
        if x % number != 0 and x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0 :
            yield x
```

`filter(condition, sequence)` method will `return` a `generator` using which you can generate new value But notice since you have used `number` as a variable it exits in the nested condition.

In future if you change the value of `number` it will generate different sequence because `number` exists in the nested condition.

Hope you got me.

Comment: Many thanks! your answer is very helpful, It's clear  now.